# JS - Quiz redirect users to pages depends of their quiz score

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question for you. I have my HTML quiz based in .js. I have set the questions etc. What is my problem is that after you finish your quiz you are redirected to the end.html page.

I need to create 2 ways of redirecting to the end.html based on your quiz score. Users who are above 80 points score need to be redirected to success.html and users under 80 points need to be redirected to fail.html

My code is here

```
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
const questionCounterText = document.getElementById("questionCounter");
const scoreText = document.getElementById("score");

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuesions = [];

let questions = [
{
question: "Otázka 1",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 1
},
{
question: "Otázka 2",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 3",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 4
},
{
question: "Otázka 4",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 5",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 6",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 7",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 8",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 9",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 10",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 11",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 12",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 13",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 14",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},
{
question: "Otázka 15",
choice1: "1",
choice2: "2",
choice3: "3",
choice4: "4",
answer: 3
},

];

//CONSTANTS
const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 15;


startGame = () => {
questionCounter = 0;
score = 0;
availableQuesions = [...questions];
getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS && score > 80 ) {
//go to the end page
return window.location.assign("/success.html");
} else if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS && score < 80 ){
    return window.location.assign("/fail.html");
} 
questionCounter++;
questionCounterText.innerText = `${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;

const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);
currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];
question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

choices.forEach(choice => {
const number = choice.dataset["number"];
choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
});

availableQuesions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
acceptingAnswers = true;
};

choices.forEach(choice => {
choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

acceptingAnswers = false;
const selectedChoice = e.target;
const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

const classToApply =
  selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

if (classToApply === "correct") {
  incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
}

selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

setTimeout(() => {
  selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
  getNewQuestion();
  }, 1000);
 });
 });

 incrementScore = num => {
 score += num;
 scoreText.innerText = score;
 };

startGame();
```

This is the part of code which I have tried to use for redirection but It is only redirecting to success html.

```
getNewQuestion = () => {
if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS && score > 80 ) {
//go to the end page
return window.location.assign("/success.html");
} else if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS && score < 80 ){
    return window.location.assign("/fail.html");
}
```

Thank you for all your answers to help me find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).  Using `||` is a popular shortcut in javascript.  If the first value is true, it doesn't even bother executing the rest of the expression.  `availableQuestions.length` is probably 0 at this point so it will always execute the first statement block.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let a = ((i >> 2) & 1) > 0;
  let b = ((i >> 1) & 1) > 0;
  let c = ((i >> 0) & 1) > 0;
  console.log(`${a} || ${b} && ${c} is ${a || b && c}`);
}
```

Sounds like you don't need that first condition at all.  From your comment, I would recommend starting with the condition that the game is over (`questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS`) and checking the score inside that condition:

```js
if (questionCount >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
  if (score >= 80) {
    return window.location.assign("/uspel.html");
  } else {
    return window.location.assign("/neuspel.html");
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Im newbie in JS and I am trying to modify the existing solution from free downloaded template and Im still learning. Can you try to modify the function so I could see what do you mean and try if it works? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your help, you gave me an idea. I have found a solution with removing the availablequestions.length which was set to 0 and modified my code like this



      `if (score >80 &&  questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {

      //go to the end page
      return window.location.assign("/uspel.html");
      } else if (score < 80 && questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS ){
  return window.location.assign("/neuspel.html");
      }`

Comment: Great!  Since they both deal with `questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTSIONS`, you might want to start with that as an if and have the score count inside that statement block.  Adding code to my answer...

Comment: Thank you :) hope after sometime I will get better in js :-D :)